# ChartJS 4.4.0: Is there a way to get some kind of onLeave event at the chart?

Tags: chart.js

I have a chart without any grid on the x-axis and I would like to show a dashed line at the dataset of the x-axis that is hovered.
I managed to add this dashed line by using the `onHover` function, but I can't detect that the mouse left the chart.
As far as I can see, there is no `onLeave` function for the chart.

Has someone an idea, how I could get this to work?

I have created a minimal Codepen for this problem: https://codepen.io/rbierbauer/pen/KKbZKjy
When hovering through the chart, the dashed line is added, but it can't be removed on mouseleave.

I also tried a custom interaction, but also there I only get the hover events and not the mouseleave event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could let you ChartJS listen to the `mouseOut` event.
<sup>*https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html#event-option*</sup>

Then use a custom plugin to catch that event and remove the lines:

```
plugins: [{
    id: 'someEventCatcher',
    beforeEvent(chart, args, pluginOptions) {
        if (args.event.type === 'mouseout') {
            chart.options.scales.x.grid.color = new Array(5).fill('transparent');
            chart.update();
        }
    }
}],
```

---

I've also added the following to the `onHover` function:

```
if (!chartElement.length) {
    return;
}
```

This will prevent `chartElement[0].index;` from failing if there is nothing you're hovering over

---

Small demo based on your codepen

```js
const chartCanvas = document.getElementById('chart-canvas');
const chart = new Chart(chartCanvas, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['December 2022','January 2023','February 2023','March 2023','Aprile 2023'],
    datasets: [ 
      {
        label: 'Label 1',
        data: [10020, 4120, 63510, 13220, 11225],
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#C6AB8D',
        backgroundColor: '#C6AB8D',
        pointRadius: 0,
        pointHoverRadius: 6,
      },
      {
        label: 'Label 2',
        data: [9020, 325, 6512, 7220, 4220],
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#ffffff',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        pointRadius: 0,
        pointHoverRadius: 6,
      }                                              
    ]
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'someEventCatcher',
    beforeEvent(chart, args, pluginOptions) {
      if (args.event.type === 'mouseout') {
        chart.options.scales.x.grid.color = new Array(5).fill('transparent');
        chart.update();
      }
    }
  }],
  options: {
  events: ['mousemove', 'mouseout', 'click', 'touchstart', 'touchmove'],
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    interaction: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        offset: true,
        border: {
          color: 'rgba(255, 245, 236, 0.4)',
          dash: [4,4]
        },
        grid: {
          color: 'transparent',
        },
        ticks: {
          color: 'rgba(255, 245, 236, 0.4)',
        }
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        border: {
          color: 'rgba(255, 245, 236, 0.4)',
        },
        grid: {
          color: 'rgba(255, 245, 236, 0.1)',
        },
        ticks: {
          color: 'rgba(255, 245, 236, 0.4)',
        }
      }
    },
    onHover: (event, chartElement) => {
    
    if (!chartElement.length) {
    
        return;
    }
      const index = chartElement[0].index;
      const totalCount = chart.data.labels.length;

      const gridColors = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
        if (i == index) {
          gridColors.push('rgba(255, 245, 236, 0.4)');
        } else {
          gridColors.push('transparent');
        }
      }
      chart.options.scales.x.grid.color = gridColors;

      chart.update();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<div style="background: rgba(0, 23, 47, 1);">
  <canvas id="chart-canvas" height="600"></canvas>
</div>
```